# Why the max filename can be 293 characters only?

Tags: windows, dart, file, windows-11

The purpose of below program is to find out what is the maximum length of filename that can be created.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  const path = "./tree"; // directory inside of with new files will be created
  const limit = 1000000; // MAX filename length
  const char = "A";

  final treeDir = Directory(path);

  // Delete the directory is its exists
  if (treeDir.existsSync()) treeDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
  // Create the directory
  if (!treeDir.existsSync()) await treeDir.create();

  for (int length in List.generate(limit, (len) => len)) {
    print("Testing $length");

    final filePath =
        "$path/${char * length}.dat"; // File with filename of size length
    await File(filePath).writeAsString("$length"); // Create's a file
  }
}

extension on String {
  // Repeat a string multiple times
  String operator *(final int length) {
    final StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) buffer.write(this);
    return buffer.toString();
  }
}
```

System info:

```
Edition Windows 11 Home Single Language
Version 22H2
File System : NTFS
```

The maximum filename which the above code generated was 293 after that the program generated error which the filename length was 294:

```
Unhandled exception:
PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = './tree/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.dat' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
, errno = 3)
#0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:42:9)
#1      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:364:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (fileTesting.dart:18:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I then removed the `max` file length limitation([Remove max file name limit](https://thegeekpage.com/make-windows-11-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/)) from the `registry` but still don't understand why I'm not able to create file with long name?

Comment: Your whole path when it failed was 301 (294 + len("./tree/")). So the limit is 300. Why? Well, no idea, that why this is a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: the `tree` directory path is `C:\Users\devpa\Documents\code\testing\testing\dart-dev\tree` and inside of this various files are created.

Comment: I would consider the authoritative source to be [the MSDN documentation on path limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later).  My guess is that `longPathAware` is not set in the application manifest.

Comment: @jamesdlin Is the the application here is dart sdk?

Comment: It would depend on how you're running your program.  If you're compiling a Windows application, then it would be the manifest for the generated `.exe` file.  If you're running a `.dart` file in interpreted mode, then yes, it should be for `dart.exe`.